# Sound disappeared on my MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

I haven't turned my MyBook on for probably six months or so, but when I turned it on today I noticed that I do not hear sound from the internal speakers.

What can the problem it?

My system:

[image]

My sound settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT1:**

[image]

Comment: Can you get audio when you plug in earbuds or headphones to the Line Out (headphone) jack?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes, I hear the sound from Headphones when I select them, see EDIT1

Comment: @IconDaemon but I do not hear sound when I switch back to internal speakers.

Comment: Test the Mac by creating a temporary new user and see if the sound problem disappears for that user.

Comment: @IconDaemon Added a new user, restarted MacBook, but still no sound.

Comment: @Dmitriano Did you get it worked ? Any solutions ?

Comment: @AhamedSafnaj no I did not.

Comment: @Dmitriano So u still have this issue ?

Comment: @AhamedSafnaj yes, absolutely